# legacy redirection with symfony routing bug?

Tags: symfony

I would like to redirect (301) all the requests like "/cgi/.*" to a "parking" page of my symfony (3.4) application "/park".

I've created a route like this :

```
old_legacy:
    path: /cgi/{catchall}
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:urlRedirect
        path: /park
        permanets: true
    requirements:
        catchall: ".*"
```

Everything is ok when urls are "/cgi/foo/bar", "cgi/bar.php?x=2", etc., but it doesn't work when the URL end with "index.php" : "/cgi/index.php", "cgi/foo/index.php?x=2".

I goes in symfony code (same for SF master) and I found something wrong for my case:

To get baseUrl, the `HttpFoundation/Request` object try to get the php script filename "SCRIPT_FILENAME", but if the **basename** is the same as SCRIPT_NAME, it get this one !

Ok, but SCRIPT_FILENAME is "/var/www/public/index.php" and SCRIPT_NAME is "/cgi/index.php", and both basename are "index.php", thus, base URL is calculated with "/cgi/index.php" which is wrong, and the base URL become "null".
At the end of the story, the router look for the path "/" and not "/cgi/index.php".

Do other people have this issue ?

Comment: Is it a misconfiguration of my PHP/apache ?

Comment: any htaccess???

Comment: The default .htaccess that comes with the symfony web package actually serves all files that actually exist before going to the frontend controller. Does `/cgi/index.php` actually exist perhaps?

Comment: Why don't you just do this in your webserver / .htaccess file?

Comment: "/cgi/index.php" does'nt exists, and apache rewrite forward everything except some statics to "/var/www/public/index.php"

Comment: For a basic symfony configuration, when you dump $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] and $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], what is the result for URL like "/something/index.php" ?